# Bluetooth tests with React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, avd-manager

Im trying to use bluetooth (to connect a vibration sensor to the app) on a react-native application.
I tried using [react-native-ble-plx](https://polidea.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/) but I have a problem: when I emulate an Android Device with AVD Manager from Android Studio, how is bluetooth suppose to work? Does my PC bluetooth transmit informations to the emulated device?

Comment: Actually : how can i test the bluetooth side of my application while emulating it ?

Comment: I didnt tag "Android Studio"....

Comment: [Yes, you did.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55881419/revisions).

Comment: Android Studio was present in revision 1 - I removed it. The link also verifies that.

Comment: okay you edited it, thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2):

Android Devise Emulator from Android Studio not support Bluetooth. You can use only real Android device.